# What do these "\e6##" characters mean?

Tags: css

https://www.keysurgical.com/assets/scss/objectsCustom/_icons.scss

I'm trying to figure out what all these "\e6##" references mean. Is "\e" some sort of special character?

```
.icon-logo-mark:before {
    content: "\e601";
}
.icon-burger:before {
    content: "\e602";
}
.icon-arrow-down:before {
    content: "\e603";
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Put simply, they're Unicode references.  The "\e601", for example, is the hex code 0xe601.  If you go here: http://unicodelookup.com/#0xe601/1  you'll see that the entry for that character is totally blank.  It's in a part of the Unicode character set reserved for "private" use.  Meaning icon libraries and the like can place whatever they want in those spots and not have to worry about overriding common characters like those of any of the alphabets of the world or a Chinese character, for instance.