# What is content in CSS before or after?

Tags: html, css

```
.icon-a:before { content: '\e803'; }
.icon-b:before { content: '\e96f'; }
```

Okay I know content can be used to render URL or quotes but what is happening in the above code?

I came across this code and it is confusing, I tried googling I can't find any.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: there are hell lot of resources available explaining how :before works.See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp ...

Comment: i know how :before works, i want to know what is content: '\e803'; ?

Comment: see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content

Answer (score 1):

Quoting papiro as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995461/what-do-these-e6-characters-mean?answertab=active#tab-top)

> Put simply, they're Unicode references. The "\e601", for example, is the hex code 0xe601. If you go here: http://unicodelookup.com/#0xe601/1 you'll see that the entry for that character is totally blank. It's in a part of the Unicode character set reserved for "private" use. Meaning icon libraries and the like can place whatever they want in those spots and not have to worry about overriding common characters like those of any of the alphabets of the world or a Chinese character, for instance.

In your case \e803 reffers to unicode character [this](https://www.utf8icons.com/character/59395/UTF-8-character)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It depends on font you are corrently using in parent element. This code is Unicode character code, which can display �. After \ code of character is entered.